# How to bring all numbers in word to front in shell

Tags: bash, unix, sh

Input File:

```
new12
abc34
none44
bore93
this67
```

Output should be:

```
12new
34abc
44none
93bore
67this
```

How to do it with commands in a Unix shell script?

Comment: Why a space in `12 new` and no space anywhere else?  What should happen with `qqq12rrr23sss` as an input line?

Answer (score 5):

You may use sed.

```
sed 's/^\([^[:digit:]]\+\)\([[:digit:]]\+\)$/\2\1/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Awk:

```
{
    w = d = ""
    n = split($1, c, "")
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        if (c[i] ~ /[[:alpha:]]/)
            w = w c[i]
        else
            d = d c[i]
    print d w
}
```

```
$ awk -f switch.awk file
12new
34abc
44none
93bore
67this
```

To print in the right order, the word is split into an array of characters used to build word and number strings depending if they match the regex `[[:alpha:]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Only bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

switch(){   tail="${var##*[[:digit:]]}"
            head="${var%$tail}"
            echo -e "in  :$var\t out : $tail$head";      }



while read -r var; do
    switch "$var"
done <<-_testwords_
12new
34abc
44none
93bore
67this
87ert67ter
ak356ajf43
_testwords_
```